# Running Perl in WIndows

Tags: windows, perl, scripting, firewall

I am having trouble running a perl script and it keeps on giving me this error.

```
C:\Users\heitadmin\Desktop\360AnalyticsLtd\360-FAAR-v0.4.6\360-FAAR>perl 360-faar.pl
Can't locate Text/Shellwords.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware vSphere CLI/Perl/site/lib C:/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware vSphere CLI/Perl/lib .) at 360-faar.pl line 239.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 360-faar.pl line 239.
```

The script I am trying to run is a firewall audit tool:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/faar/?source=typ_redirect

I am using the DWIM Perl for Windows on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

The packge `Text::Shellwords` is not installed on your system.

You might want to try to install it like so:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Text::Shellwords"
```

Comment: I ran this and it seems to download it from a repository and I verify that Shellwords was also in the lib folder and changed the name to make sure it is not failing due to case sensitive issues but still getting the same errors. Is it possible it is caused by limitation in the windows environment?